# (Bash) Trying to make a until..do function using a number guessing game

Tags: bash

```
dountil() {

    #Prompt user below to guess randomly-generated number between 1 and 10
    
    (( answer = $RANDOM % 1-10 ))
    
    until [[ $guess -eq answer ]]
     do
     read -p "Enter a number between 1 and 10:" guess
     if [[ $guess -ne answer ]]; then
     echo "Incorrect. Try again"
     elif [[ $guess -eq answer ]]; then
     echo "Correct! Want to play again?"
     read -p prompt
     if [[ $prompt = yes ]]
     dountil
     if [[ $prompt = no ]]
     then
     echo "Goodbye."
    fi
    };
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and I hit a wall almost every time. Some errors I've fixed, but then new ones appear. As it is now, I get

syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: https://shellcheck.net - use it to find syntax errors and foot guns.

Comment: I see an `until; ...do` but no corresponding `done`

Comment: I see `if`s without an appropriate number of `fi`s, and also, what happens when a user enters `a coffee, please, milk, but no sugar, will you?` instead of `yes` or `no`.

Comment: and here I come around and tell you that recursion is the wrong software design approach (it *almost always is* in most programming languages you meet, unless your problem actually is a recursive one. This isn't.); your program, even if you correct all mistakes, will rapidly exhaust stack space, and you'll feel like someone programming a 1960's computer, wondering why a couple hundred iterations make your program stop working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always write code with the correct indentation. The problems are obvious...

```
dountil () {
    (( answer = $RANDOM % 1-10 ))
    until [[ $guess -eq answer ]]
    do
         read -p "Enter a number between 1 and 10:" guess
         if [[ $guess -ne answer ]]; then
             echo "Incorrect. Try again"
         elif [[ $guess -eq answer ]]; then
             echo "Correct! Want to play again?"
             read -p prompt
             if [[ $prompt = yes ]]
                 dountil
                 if [[ $prompt = no ]]
                 then
                     echo "Goodbye."
                 fi
}
```

At least two `then`, two `fi` and one `done` missing. And calling the function again from within, what is that?

On your level of coding you really should add only one or two commands at a time and then run the new version of the script. Just in order to easily catch syntax problems.

## avoid recursion

### there is no need for a function anyway

```
while true; do
    # ...
    if [[ $prompt != yes ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

### make the funcion a loop

```
dountil () {
    while true; do
        # ...
        if [[ $prompt != yes ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

### put only the core code in the function

```
guess_number () {
    (( answer = $RANDOM % 1-10 ))
    read -p "Enter a number between 1 and 10: " guess
    if [[ $guess -ne answer ]]; then
        echo "Incorrect."
    else
        echo "Correct."
    fi
}

while true; do
    guess_number
    # ...
    if [[ $prompt != yes ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I've only been scripting a couple weeks through college and the instructions I have aren't the greatest. I've been trying to do this particular one for awhile, and I've ran out of ideas which is why I asked here. As for calling the function within the function, I'm meant to re-do the loop again if the user answers yes, with another number, but I don't know how to make it loop around without calling the function a second time.

Comment: @CrypticTexas See my edit

Comment: note that `(( answer = $RANDOM % 1-10 ))` will always set `answer` to `-10`. That parses as `($RANDOM % 1) - 10`, and anything modulo 1 is always zero... You need `(( answer = $RANDOM % 10 + 1 ))` to get something between 1 and 10. (And note that there's some slight bias there since RANDOM goes up to some power of 2, not a round base 10 number.)